# How to append c-style string or string literals to std::vector<char*>?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying to append **string literals** to `std::vector<char*>` but whatever I try i can not append them.

```
std::vector<char*> vector1;

vector1.push_back("examplestring"); // gives warning C++11 does not allow conversion form string literal..

const char* anotherstring = "examplestring"; 
vector1.push_back(anotherstring);   // gives error no matchcing member to call push_back
```

Can someone please correct me with the proper way of adding string to the vector?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have a `std::vector<char*>` in the first place? Why not a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: I  am using deprecated function from Security Framework on macOS which requires argument  char* nonull const* arguments

Comment: Your vector has `char *`s. In C++, you cannot assign a `const char *` to a `char *`, and you cannot add `const char *`s to the vector, either. That's simply how C++ works.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `std::string` manages its own buffer of characters and setting external pointers to it may invalidate those pointers if string is changed later.

Comment: and I am passing the vector1 to the function like this:   &vector1[0]

Comment: @user123445151156: Dare I ask why you would ever intentionally use deprecated *security-related* functions in new code?!?

Comment: @user123445151156 You can store `std::vector<std::string> vector1` and pass elements to the external function as `vector1[i].data()`.

Comment: @user123445151156 What does the function do with the strings you pass to it? The correct approach really depends on the answer to that question.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am currently trying to find but it looks like there is no new function as replacement for this one, also it is not reccomended to use the funciton but there is no currently other way

Comment: @john execute command, and in vector are the arguments

Comment: "_which requires argument char* nonull const* arguments_" What does this mean? Can that be `vector<char const*>`? Then no problem. Otherwise, you need another solution, such as what **john** suggested (or if the function _definitely_ never tries to modify the strings and just has the wrong API, then `const_cast`)

Comment: You can use `strncpy` to convert `std::string::c_str()` result to `char*` and append that to the vector.

Comment: @user123445151156 So if I understand this right, the function effectively takes an array of char* arguments which are not modified by the function. You could just `const_cast`, that should work. I.e. `vector.push_back(const_cast<char*>("some string"));`

Comment: thank you all for your time for helping me. I solved this like @john specified and like the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `const_cast` to cast away `const`-ness for the sake of passing a const object where a non-const object is expected by an interface. Note, however, that this is just for bridging the interface; the function to which you pass the (casted) const-value (or any other part accessing the passed object) must not alter the object, though. This would yield undefined behaviour:

```
std::vector<char*> vector1;

const char* anotherstring = "examplestring";
char* anotherStringNonConst = const_cast<char*>(anotherstring);

vector1.push_back(anotherStringNonConst);
```

Comment: this solved my problem. thank you very much, also for @john  who  mentioned the same solution in the comments.

Comment: It is not safe. Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior

Comment: @userbb So... if the function _doesn't_ actually attempt to modify the `char*` pointing at a string literal, there's no UB... The answer explicitly stated that this is only for cases where one can be sure (by referring to the source code or asking a developer) that the function will not do so. If that is satisfied, there can't be any UB.

Comment: agree. answer stated and has hands clean. But why we cannot allocate memory to be perfectly sure.

Answer (score 3):

For starters in your code snippet there is no object of the type `std::string`. You code snippet deals with string literals.

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays.

So for example the string literal used in this call

```
vector1.push_back("examplestring");
```

can not be converted from the type `const char[14]` to the type `char *`.

If you are going to store in the vector only pointers to string literals then you should declare the vector like

```
std::vector<const char *> vector1;
```

Otherwise you need to dynamically allocate strings and push them on the vector. For example

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<char *> vector1;

char *s = new char[ sizeof( "examplestring" )];
std::strcpy( s, "examplestring" );
vector1.push_back( s );
```

When the vector will not be needed any more you have to free the allocated memory for stored strings.

If you want to store objects of the type `std::string` nevertheless you have to create copies of the objects using dynamic memory allocation. Otherwise the lifetime of strings should be at least not less than the lifetime of the vector.

For example

```
std::vector<char *> vector1;
std::string str( "examplestring" );

char *s = new char[ str.size() + 1];
std::strcpy( s, str.c_str() );
vector1.push_back( s );
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to append `std::string` to `std::vector<char*>`?

Example:

```
std::string example;
std::vector<char*> vector1;
vector1.push_back(example.data());
```

Note that you must be careful to keep `example` alive for at least as long as pointer is being used. And you mustn't modify the string in ways that would invalidate the pointer.

Comment: hmm maybe that is problem because this solution give me no matching member function to call push back

Comment: @user123445151156 Whoops, I forgot. You need to use `data()` to get pointer to non-const.

Comment: again no  luck, is it working in your case? maybe i am doing something wrong

Comment: @user123445151156 It won't work if you use an ancient compiler. In such case you can cast the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
//#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<const char*> vector1;

    vector1.push_back("examplestring");
    const char* anotherstring = "examplestring";
    vector1.push_back(anotherstring);

    for (auto* pCstring : vector1) {
        printf("%s\n", pCstring);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using `std::vector<const char*>` works, but still suggest strongly to use `std::vector<std::string>` for memory safety.